# Reading Encrypted Data from S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have to download data from an S3 bucket , the data is encrypted and I have the kms key to decrypt data .The code is running in an EC2 instane and the EC2 instance is having the IAM role to read from S3 .
I have seen a sample code in [this](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonS3/latest/dev/client-side-using-kms-java.html) link ,but I am not able to read the contents .I am getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials into profile [default]: AWS Access Key ID is not specified.
        at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.internal.ProfileStaticCredentialsProvider.fromStaticCredentials(ProfileStaticCredentialsProvider.java:55)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.internal.ProfileStaticCredentialsProvider.<init>(ProfileStaticCredentialsProvider.java:40)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.fromProfile(ProfilesConfigFile.java:207)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.getCredentials(ProfilesConfigFile.java:160)
```

Can somebody suggest where I am going wrong or give some guidelines on how to read encrypted data from S3 buckets without credentials

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution by providing InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider .Below is the code .

```
 String kms_key = Constants.KMS_key;
        String inputString = null;
        KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider materialProvider = new KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider(kms_key);
        AmazonS3EncryptionClient client = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getInstance(),
                materialProvider);
        S3Object downloadedObject = client.getObject(bucketName, filePath);
        if (null != downloadedObject) {
            inputString = convertToString(downloadedObject.getObjectContent());
        }
```